# Nesting an identity matrix within another larger matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to create an NxN matrix, which has a 1 on the bottom left entry, and then in the top right there is a (N-1) identity matrix. I've tried every way I can think of and can't seem to do this but I am fairly new to python, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? It's not becoming clear what the problem was, or in what representation you want to create this matrix.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sure, I have been getting the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." while using the following (where i have defined the matrix as T): T = zeros((N,N))
T[(N-1),0] = 1 
T[0,(N-1)] = identity((N-1))

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with any application of matrices that are comprised of a mix of scalars and other matrices. Care to share an example?

Comment: @Woodford It is all scalars, it is just a simplification of writing It out

Comment: An N-1 identity matrix isn't a scalar, it's a matrix. All of your matrix elements are scalars except the top-right element, which is another matrix.

Comment: @Woodford but as all the elements of the identity matrix are scalars, if one were to write this out in full it would be an NxN matrix with 1 or 0 entries. I am trying to include the Identity part in the code still as it helps with the generalisation to any N value i thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest with numpy:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> N = 4
>>> np.roll(np.identity(N), 1, axis=1)
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

With vanilla python:

```
>>> N = 4
>>> matrix = [[0]*N for _ in range(N)]
>>> for i in range(N):
        matrix[i][(i+1)%N] = 1
>>> matrix
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: sorry if this is dumb question but how would this work for any N if we have to manually type out the array at the end?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this question. For the answer given all you have to do is define `N`. The code will build the matrix. The blocks above are actually showing you the output at the end.